# weird situation with file permissions on windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

so my project is structured as followed. I have a cherrypy server and a backend server that executes some operation. Now I have a 'main' app.py file that handles starting these processes. They are started like:

```
    SERVER = subprocess.Popen([PYTHON_EXE_PATH, '-m', WEB_SERVER, 
                                    'tvb'], shell=False)

    BACKEND = subprocess.Popen([PYTHON_EXE_PATH, '-m', 'bin.rpserver'
                            , cfg.RPC_SERVER_IP, cfg.RPC_SERVER_PORT],
                            shell=False)
```

Now after they are started these pids are stored in a file, so the user can run a stop script and close them. These script also works fine and is basically:

```
def execute_stop():  
    if os.path.exists(PID_FILE):  
        pid_file = open(PID_FILE, 'r')
        has_processes = False
        for pid in pid_file.read().split('\n'):
            if len(pid.strip()):
                try:
                    if sys.platform == 'win32':
                        import ctypes
                        handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(1, False, 
                                                                int(pid))
                        ctypes.windll.kernel32.TerminateProcess(handle, -1)
                        ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
                    else:
                        os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL) 
                except Exception, _:
                    has_processes = True
        if has_processes:
            sys.stdout.write("Some old PIDs were still registered; \
                          They could not be stopped.")                    
        pid_file.close()
    pid_file = open(PID_FILE, "w")
    pid_file.close()
```

Now this pid file, along with my logger file and the other data files that are created are held in a `cfg.STORAGE`, and I also have a simple clean procedure for that:

```
def execute_clean():
    """Remove TVB folder, TVB File DB, and log file."""
    try:
        if os.path.isdir(cfg.TVB_STORAGE):
            shutil.rmtree(cfg.TVB_STORAGE)
    except Exception, excep1:
        sys.stdout.write("Could not remove storage folder!")
        sys.stdout.write(str(excep1))
```

This also works fine when called separately. But here is the problem: there is an option in my program that allows the user to change some settings, in which case the whole program needs to restart and the steps should be redone. For this I:

```
    cherrypy.engine.exit()
    self.logger.debug("Waiting for Cherrypy to terminate.")
    sleep(2)
    python_path = cfg().get_python_path()
    proc_params = [python_path, '-m', 'bin.app', 'start', 'web', 'backend']
    subprocess.Popen(proc_params, shell=False)
```

So this will again does basically the following steps:

```
    execute_stop()
    execute_clean()
    start both processes again
```

The weird thing, that I can't understand is that `execute_stop()` works fine, and as you can see at the end of that the `PID_FILE` is opened in write mode and closed to clear the contents, but then imediately after `execute_clean()` fails saying that `PID_FILE` is locked by another process.

Now I've checked and rechecked and each time that file is opened it's closed after and I really don't know what to look for anymore. This happens only on windows, and I've tried using dependency walker to see what is going on, and it seems that when the python processes are running, dependency walker sees 4 references and 2 handlers to those files, which is strange considering that they are closed every time. I also find it strange that I can open the files in `'w'` mode but I can't delete them.

Any ideeas what could be wrong/ what to look for would be really appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've tried using as sugested `os.waitpid` but when doing:

```
    os.waitpid(int(pid), 0)
```

I got an `[Errno 10] No child processes`. I've also read around and saw someone saying that on windows you should pass the handle instead of the pid to os.waitpid so I also tried it with the handle but I got the same result. So at that point the process should no longer exist right?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark...
My hunch is that the one or both of the SERVER, BACKEND processes are not terminating as expected and have an open PID_FILE.  Check that they each open the PID_FILE with `mode='a'` and close it promptly.  Unless I'm off base with the way SERVER/BACKEND are handling the PID_FILE you could also try `os.waitpid(pid)` after your call to `TerminateProcess`.  This should block until the process is truly terminated.